# Results are different when application tested on a physical phone and on simulator

Tags: flutter, firebase

I am trying to solve an issue with my application. When I test it on a virtual device (iPhone), the query is working well and I am getting the document I am supposed to get. When I test the application on my physical phone, the application does not find any record.

I have checked the filters, they are the same. it is exactly the same code. I have never have this situation before. Please, do you have any suggestion?

```
Future myQuery (  time,  energy,  urgent,  important ) async{
    final uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
    final path = 'Users/$uid/allTasks';
    final currentQuery = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(path);

    Query statusQuery = currentQuery.where('status', isEqualTo: 'Inbox');
   // Query contextQuery = statusQuery.where('context', isEqualTo: );
    Query timeQuery = statusQuery.where('time_Needed', isEqualTo: time);
    Query energyQuery = timeQuery.where('energy_Needed', isEqualTo: energy);
    Query urgentQuery = energyQuery.where('urgent', isEqualTo: urgent);
    Query importantQuery = urgentQuery.where('important', isEqualTo: important);

    final snapshot = await importantQuery.get();
    final data = snapshot.docs;

    if(data.isNotEmpty) {
      return snapshot;
    }
  }
```

```
 ElevatedButton(child:
                      const Text('FIND'),
                          onPressed: () async {

                            Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) =>
                                     EngageDisplayTasks(
                                      time: timeSelectedPicker!, energy: energySelectedPicker!,
                                      urgent: urgentWhere, important: importantWhere,
                                      )));
                          }
                      ),
```

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    myQuery(time,energy,urgent,important).then((results) {
      setState(() {
        querySnapshot = results;
      });
    });

 queryEngage(time,energy,urgent,important).then((results) {
      setState(() {
        querySnapshot = results;
      });
    });  
  }
```

```
 Future queryEngage (time,energy,urgent,important) async {
    await myQueryV2();
    await myQueryV3 (statusQuery,time);
    await myQueryV4 (timeQuery,energy);
    await myQueryV5 (energyQuery,urgent);
    await myQueryV6 (urgentQuery,important);
  }
```

```
Future myQueryV2 ( ) async{
    final uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
    final path = 'Users/$uid/allTasks';
    final currentQuery = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(path);

     statusQuery = currentQuery.where('status', isEqualTo: 'Inbox');
     return statusQuery;
  }

  Future myQueryV3 (statusQuery, time) async {

     timeQuery = statusQuery.where('time_Needed', isEqualTo: time);

     return timeQuery;
  }

  Future myQueryV4 (timeQuery, energy) async {
     energyQuery = timeQuery.where('energy_Needed', isEqualTo: energy);

     return energyQuery;
  }

  Future myQueryV5 (energyQuery, urgent) async {

     urgentQuery = energyQuery.where('urgent', isEqualTo: urgent);
     return urgentQuery;
  }

  Future myQueryV6 (urgentQuery, important) async {

     importantQuery = urgentQuery.where('important', isEqualTo: important);

    print ('urgent: $urgent');
    print ('important: $important');
    print ('time: $time');
    print ('energy: $energy');

    final snapshot = await importantQuery.get();
    final data = snapshot.docs;

    if(data.isNotEmpty) {
      return snapshot;
    }
  }
```

Comment: please post a minimal code that reproduces the same behavior.

Comment: There are few things that simulator cannot work like real device, such as cannot receive notification, picker image doesn't work well... Please provide which function you are testing, and the code of this module

Comment: I have added the query

Comment: Should be `snapshot.data()`. Also, are you sure you want to `return snapshot` if there is data? Seems this would create an infinite loop always calling your `get()` request over and over when data is returned.

Comment: @Tim: What do you mean by snapshot.data()? If you are refering to if(data.isNotEmpty) {
      return snapshot;
    } I have tried but I am getting an error : The method 'data' isn't defined for the type 'QuerySnapshot'.

Comment: @Tim, I would like to get the data based on criteria selected by the user. Then, all the documents matching those criteria will be displayed in a listview.builder

Comment: @LaurentThomas - I see. So are you intending for all queries to run? Because at the moment, you are only calling `get()` on the one.

Comment: yes. The first query is supposed to execute, then the second one will be executed on the result of the first query, the third one executed on the result of the second one etc...

Comment: You would need to await each query to accomplish this. Or else the results are not available to the subsequent query. I would also suggest some error checking along the way. If any query fails, the next is not firing in your current code. Which could explain why no record is found.

Comment: I have added some code where each query is awaiting for the previous one to be executed

Comment: Sounds like you're looking more for a compound query than a chain. Posting example now...

Comment: Yes. This is correct. I would like to do a compound query.  Some value are String and unique. But for two of them, the data are Array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a single compound query like this. It is not necessary to get the results at each stage based on the code shown. You may need to create some composite indexes to improve optimization, but Firebase should notify you automatically if this is the case.

```
Future myQuery (  time,  energy,  urgent,  important ) async{
  final uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
  final path = 'Users/$uid/allTasks';
  final currentQuery = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(path);

 try {
    final snapshot = currentQuery
        .where('status', isEqualTo: 'Inbox')
        .where('time_Needed', isEqualTo: time)
        .where('energy_Needed', isEqualTo: energy)
        .where('urgent', isEqualTo: urgent)
        .where('important', isEqualTo: important);

    await snapshot.get().then((data) {
      for (var doc in data.docs) {
        print("${doc.id} => ${doc.data()}");
      }
    });
  } catch (err) {
    print(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried, but I am getting several errors. Const variables must be initialized with a constant value. // The method 'data' isn't defined for the type 'QuerySnapshot'.

Comment: Also, in the application, the user can decide not to specify some value. What I mean is that the user could maybe decide to just filter the data by time_Needed or tasks which are important only

Comment: I updated to help with mapping the results. If each filter is meant to be optional, you may need to incorporate 'if' statements for each condition.

Comment: Many thanks. I have tried. I am getting the result on the console, but my application is still returning no record founded. I will continue to investigate

Comment: Many thank. Your code is working perfectly. I am getting the right data displayed with print in the console. What I do not understand is why querySnapshot does not contain the values coming from myQuery. Please, can you point me to the right direction? Thank you

Comment: That is indeed a challenge which requires further investigation. Can you verify that all packages are updated and Firebase is initiated properly?

Comment: Firebase is initiaded properly. It works fine with all the other view. Here I just have to find out why myQuery does not return the result so this could work return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('ACTION'),
        leading: InkWell(
            child: const Icon(Icons.close),
            onTap:() {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();}
        ),
      ),
        body: querySnapshot != null ?